# How to highlight with color only selected text?

Tags: abap

I want to highlight text who stands not at the beginning of line rather in the middle.

If I do this:

```
FORMAT INTENSIFIED COLOR = 3.
WRITE AT 120 'test'.
```

then is the whole line highlighted with color.

How can I only highlight the text section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FORMAT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapformat.htm) is to define the default formatting values for all subsequent output ABAP list statements like `WRITE`, and consequently it also applies to the whole lines (unless other formatting values are given specifically to the output texts and fields).

[`WRITE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapwrite-.htm) has the same `INTENSIFIED` and `COLOR` words (and more), which behave identically to `FORMAT` words, but they will apply only to the text mentioned:

```
WRITE AT 120 'test' INTENSIFIED COLOR = 3.
```

You can find more information in [ABAP documentation - WRITE - ext_format_options](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapwrite_ext_options.htm)

Answer (score 1):

For highlighting text, there are several examples available.

Follwing are two sap standard demo programs.

1. DEMO_LIST_FORMAT_COLOR_1
2. DEMO_LIST_FORMAT_COLOR_2

You can use INTENSIFIED WITH WRITE statment to get the required resulte.

```
WRITE AT 120 'test' INTENSIFIED COLOR COL_TOTAL.
```